# Cannot catch exception from shared library in main.cpp

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, shared-libraries, try-catch

I'm currently working on a game with a plugin based architecture. The executable consists mostly of a shared library loader and a couple of interface definitions. All the interesting stuff is happening in dynamic shared libraries which are loaded at start up.

One of the library classes throws an exception under certain circumstances. I would expect to be able to catch this exception and do useful stuff with it but this is where it gets weird. See following simplified example code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
  try
  {
    Application app;
    app.loadPlugin();
    app.doStuffWithPlugin();
    return 0;
  }
  catch(const std::exception& ex)
  {
     // Log exception
     return 1;
  }
}
```

**Application.cpp**

```
...
void doStuffWithPlugin()
{
  plugin.doStuff();
}
...
```

**Plugin.cpp**

```
...
void doStuff()
{
   throw exception_derived_from_runtime_error("Something is wrong");
}
...
```

Plugin.cpp exists in a dynamic shared library which is successfully loaded and which has afterwards created an object of class Plugin. The exception_derived_from_runtime_error is defined in the application. There is no `throw()` or `noexcept`.

I would expect to catch the exception_derived_from_runtime_error in main but that doesn't happen. Compiled with GCC 4.8 using C++11 the application crashes with `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.`.

I replaced `catch(const std::exception& ex)` with `catch(...)` but that didn't make any difference. The weird part is if i catch the exception in doStuffWithPlugin() it works. If i rethrow it using `throw;` it fails again but it can be caught if i use `throw ex;`:

**Application.cpp**

```
void doStuffWithPlugin()
{
  try
  {
      plugin.doStuff();
  }
  catch(const exception_derived_from_runtime_error& ex)
  {
     // throw; <- Not caught in main().
     // throw ex; <- Caught in main().
  }
}
```

Hopefully somebody has an idea. Thanks for every help you can give.

Comment: How are you loading the library at runtime?

Comment: By simply using `::LoadLibraryA` on Windows and `::dlopen` on Linux. Both work perfectly. After loaded i optain a function pointer to some `getPlugin()` function (this the library ABI) which creates the Plugin-object. I should mention that every method works fine. Only throwing exceptions causes an odd behavior.

Comment: Did you verify that indeed an `exception_derived_from_runtime_error` was thrown from the C++ code?  I ask since a runtime exception in Windows is not a C++ exception (it is an SE exception).  Catching runtime exceptioons requires that SE handling is turned on (this can be done in Visual Studio, don't know about gcc).

Comment: Shouldn't the catch in doStuffWithPlugin() fail if it isn't a `exception_derived_from_runtime_error`? And what do you mean by "SE exception"?

Comment: @tea2code SE (Structured Exception) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For example, access violations are *not* C++ exceptions.  To allow C++ code to catch these exceptions, the code needs to be adjusted.  As my comment mentioned, for Visual Studio, it is just a matter of flipping a setting at compile time.  I don't know what the steps are for gcc.

Comment: The caught exception definitely contains the message set in Plugin (using `ex.what()`) so I'm pretty sure it is the correct one. Also as mentioned even i can catch the exception in the Application class.

Comment: Even putting `plugin.doStuff();` directly into main doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a problem with destroying the library handle before catching the exception? After putting try-catch around `app.doStuffWithPlugin();` (which means the Plugin object, library handle and everything else is still alive in catch) it works.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Linux with libdl and GCC...

Comment: Didn't test it under Linux so possible that this is a Windows specific problem. As mentioned in the comment before putting `Application app;` (which contains the loaded library handle) before `try` solves the problem. Currently I'm curious if somebody can explain this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this seems to be a problem with shared libraries on Windows. The behavior occurs if the library is unloaded and an object created in this libraries remains in memory. The application seems to crash immediately. The only reference to this problems are found if gcc as an cross compiler or MinGW is used. See also https://www.sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2005-01/msg00022.html